# Recorrer div padre

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo un div padre, y dentro de el varios divs de la siguiente manera:

```
<div id="messagesTable">

    <div id="white" ><span>white --- ggg</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- nocambiar</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
```

Lo que pretendo es recorrer con jQuery o JavaScript el `div` `#messagesTable`, identificar los `div` que son id `#red`, y después obtener el `span` que esta en ese `div` `#red`, si el span tiene como valor el texto "cambiar" entonces a ese div cambiarle el atributo id a white por ejemplo.

Comment: Tenes un error **gravísimo**, jamas uses el mismo `id` más de una vez a lo largo de un documento, deben ser **únicos**, te recomiendo, que, para solucionar tu problema, leas acerca de las [clases](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

Comment: entiendo q no debo repetrir los id, pero asi me plantearon el diseño de la pagina

Comment: Cambialos por el uso de class, sino vas a tener problemas futuros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice un pequeño código que realiza tu planteamiento:

```js
$('#messagesTable > div[id="red"]').find('span').filter(function() {
  
  var palabra = "cambiar";
  if(new RegExp("\\b" + palabra + "\\b").test($(this).text())){
    console.log($(this).text());
    $(this).css({"background":"black","color":"white"});
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div id="messagesTable">

    <div id="white" ><span>white --- ggg</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- nocambiar</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
    
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Utilice el **filter()** para esto y emplee una regla donde busco exactamente la palabra "cambiar".

Espero te sirva.

Comment: @PolloKulos creo que esto te servira

Answer (score 0):

Los id deben ser únicos. En tal caso, si deseas identificar varios elementos puedes hacerlo con un atributo "name" o bien asignando una clase. Pero respetando tu ejemplo, lo deberías hacer así:

Debería quedar algo así

```js
function changeText(val){
  //seleccionamos el div "padre" por su ID
  //Luego seleccionamos los div en su interior por ID
  //finalmente le agregamos que seleccione por nombre de etiqueta el span
  $("#messagesTable #red span").text(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messagesTable">

    <div id="white" ><span>white --- ggg</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="red" ><span>red --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
    <div id="white" ><span>white --- hola</span></div>
</div>
</br>
Nuevo texto
<input id="input" placeholder="Ingresá el nuevo texto aquí" oninput="changeText(this.value)"></input>
```

:

Comment: lo que pretendo es algo asi:         $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#messagesTable").each(function () {
                var images = $(this).find("#red span");
                $(this).find("#red").hide();
            });

        });   encontrar el id red y tomar el valor del span, lo he estado haciendo con este fragmento de codigo

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice Fran Islas y Juan Salvador Portugal los atributos id son únicos, así que deberías buscar hacerlo de otra forma, esta yo propongo:

```js
function cambiar() {
  // obtener el div principal
  const messages_table = document.querySelector("#messagesTable");

  // obtener todos los span que estén dentro de un elemento de clase red, del div principal
  const all_cambiar_red_span = messages_table.querySelectorAll(".red > span");

  // recorrer cada uno de ellos
  for (let span of all_cambiar_red_span)
    // revisar que no contenga "nocambiar"
    if (!span.textContent.includes("nocambiar"))
       // cambiar el nombre de la clase del nodo padre(el div) a "white"
       span.parentNode.className = "white";
  
}
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="messagesTable">
    <div class="white"><span>white --- ggg</span></div>
    <div class="red"><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div class="red"><span>red --- nocambiar</span></div>
    <div class="red"><span>red --- cambiar</span></div>
    <div class="white"><span>white --- hola</span></div>
    <div class="white"><span>white --- hola</span></div>
</div>

<button onclick="cambiar()">Cambiar color</button>
```

Supongo que cuando decías

> si el span tiene como valor el texto "cambiar" entonces a ese div cambiarle...

Te referías a que si dicho contenido del div, decía cambiar con espacios, ya que todos los span continenen en sí el texto "cambiar", evalúa *cambiar* y *nocambiar* en un regex `/cambiar/` y ambos darán coincidencia: **cambiar** y no**cambiar**

Por ello busqué el string "nocambiar" en lugar de "cambiar" y luego lo negué.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Si es algo parecido a lo que busco, pero para obtener el texto del span, seria algo asi? alert(span.text());

Comment: Sí, `span.text()` si estás usando JQuery, en JavaScript puro el texto está contenido en la propiedad `textContent` así que sería así: `span.textContent`